# ToolTips for Text Possible?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am wondering if the following is possible:

Adding tooltips to a specific text (code editor) like:

```
var ToolTip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip
{
    AutomaticDelay = 5000,
    AutoPopDelay = 50000,
    InitialDelay = 100,
    ReshowDelay = 500
};

ToolTip1.SetToolTip(rtb, "Represents text as a series of Unicode characters");*/
```

But inside a text something like this:

[image]

I wonder how to do it.

Comment: any other answerpls ???

Comment: any other answer pls??? bumpz for this ...

Answer (score 0):

You must add an XML documentation above your properties like so:

```
/// <summary>
/// Add your description here
/// </summary>
public String[] xm = { "XmlReadNode", "XmlWriteNode" }
```

EDIT:
Update after question was clarified

```
/// <summary>
/// Your write description
/// </summary>
private const string write = "XmlWriteNode";

/// <summary>
/// Your read description.
/// </summary>
private const string read = "XmlReadNode";


/// <summary>
/// Add your object description here
/// </summary>
public String[] xm = 
{
    read, write 
};
```

Comment: then whats next when i have those strings? i just want to know the exact code for tooltip but editor was fixed now

Comment: I don't thinks there are any direct ways to do that in VS. However if your xm array isn't dynamic (or re-assigned anywhere) you can add each of the strings within into constants add comments to those instead, and then finally build your array using those constants. See my edit above.

Comment: what if many string sir? like public const string write = { "abstract", "as", "base" }

Comment: As I previously said, this is not something Visual Studio supports, this is why each const was used for one value only so that you could add individual descriptions to each of them.